# Realm onSuccessListener is called after long delay

Tags: android, realm

In my application I use realm on a background thread just for write transactions and on the UI thread for querying from the same file. At first I used manual transaction on background thread and noticed that notification about change arrived to the UI thread after very long time.

The DB is not very big (<1MB) and with few thousand objects at most. In the problematic transaction i iterate over a lot of objects but change values in just few of them (~4 object instances have some primitive values changed). Usually duration between beginTransaction to log after commitTransaction is around 100ms, however notification to the UI thread arrives 1-20s later (the delay seems random to me, changes in each transaction are nearly the same but delay changes..).

I tried to call realm.refresh() on UI thread after commitTransaction on the background thread was done. It kinda helped, delay was shorter but visual hang for a few seconds was terrible of course. For test i changed the implementation to executeTransactionAsync with onSuccess callback, behavior is the same, onSuccess is called long seconds after the transaction block is finished.

I tried simple profiling, background thread was fully used during the delay but not by any work i scheduled to it, it seems that realm is using it.

So my question is what is realm doing after commitTransaction() until publishing notifications? What may cause such a long time to make minor changes to DB? Are there some best practices to keep it fast? Can there be a bottleneck caused by more open realmInstances on the UI thread (each fragment has one open for queries + notification listener, more fragments are on the screen at the same time)?

//edit:
Data is nearly tree shaped. At the root are few instances of class A,
it has few primitive attributes and RealmList (list length <1000).
class B has around 30 primitive attributes (including Strings) and RealmList (length <5). Class C has around 40 primitive attributes  (including Strings) and a few RealmLists and some pointers to other RealmClasses. 
In the transaction in question, i need to change single instance of C.

//Solved by updating my schema to use backlinks on all bidirectional relations, now it is fast. From 5s to 200ms.

Comment: The configuration is irrelevant for the question, what matters is the Realm models (schema) and the actual write.

Comment: Project is private, i can't disclose full sources publicly. I now commented most of work happening in transaction (now its just writing of single int), unregistered all changelisteners and event with these changes onSuccess is called 2seconds later. If i comment the single write in the transaction, it is called few ms after transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally since Realm-Java 3.0.0, the recommendations for schema design changed a bit.

Previously if you wanted to access parent from child, and child from parent, you would need to have a schema like this:

```
class A extends RealmObject {
    private RealmList<B> children;

class B extends RealmObject {
    private RealmList<A> parents;
```

But since Realm 3.5.0 (aka when queries across backlinks were introduced), the recommendation is this:

```
class A extends RealmObject {
    private RealmList<B> children;

class B extends RealmObject {
    @LinkingObjects("children")
    private final RealmResults<A> parents = null;
```

Because bi-directional links can cause the Object-Store's diffing to run for an unusually large amount of time.

Without seeing your schema, I'd say this is your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for update, i didn't notice backlinks were added. I will definitely try to change it, but it will be a lot of work. Meantime after much trial and error, i found out, that if i close every instance of realm (with that configuration) and then perform the query, onSuccess is executed very fast after transaction. If there is any open realm instance left, it is slow, regardless whether it is on the same thread or not. Is it pointing to the problem with not using backlinks? I can send you email with generalized sources of schema and transaction if you are willing to look at them..

Comment: Closing the UI thread Realm results in that Diffs do not need to be calculated because there are no threads that need to receive updates. So I think it is caused by that, yes